# Why return null model class list for xml parsing in Flutter?

Tags: xml, flutter, dart, xml-parsing, mobile-development

Im working on parsing this xml file on Flutter with Flutter xml package. I created model class like this but when I access to cList[index].. that returning null.
If I access `snapshot.data.tarih` in main.dart , its working. But Currency class variables returning null to me.
Where am I doing wrong? Thank you.

XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="isokur.xsl"?>
<Tarih_Date Tarih="30.11.2020" Date="11/30/2020"  Bulten_No="2020/227" >
    <Currency CrossOrder="0" Kod="USD" CurrencyCode="USD">
            <Unit>1</Unit>
            <Isim>ABD DOLARI</Isim>
            <CurrencyName>US DOLLAR</CurrencyName>
            <ForexBuying>7.7892</ForexBuying>
            <ForexSelling>7.8032</ForexSelling>
            <BanknoteBuying>7.7837</BanknoteBuying>
            <BanknoteSelling>7.8149</BanknoteSelling>
            <CrossRateUSD/>
            <CrossRateOther/>
        
    </Currency>
    <Currency CrossOrder="1" Kod="AUD" CurrencyCode="AUD">
            <Unit>1</Unit>
            <Isim>AVUSTRALYA DOLARI</Isim>
            <CurrencyName>AUSTRALIAN DOLLAR</CurrencyName>
            <ForexBuying>5.7366</ForexBuying>
            <ForexSelling>5.7740</ForexSelling>
            <BanknoteBuying>5.7102</BanknoteBuying>
            <BanknoteSelling>5.8087</BanknoteSelling>
                <CrossRateUSD>1.3546</CrossRateUSD>
                <CrossRateOther/>
        
    </Currency>
    <Currency CrossOrder="2" Kod="DKK" CurrencyCode="DKK">
            <Unit>1</Unit>
            <Isim>DANİMARKA KRONU</Isim>
            <CurrencyName>DANISH KRONE</CurrencyName>
```

rates.model.dart

```
import 'package:xml/xml.dart';

class TarihDate {
  String tarih;
  List<Currency> cList;

  TarihDate._(this.tarih, this.cList);

  factory TarihDate.fromElement(XmlElement xmlElement) {
    return TarihDate._(
        xmlElement.getAttribute("Tarih"),
        xmlElement
            .findElements("Currency")
            .map((e) => Currency.fromElement(e))
            .toList());
  }
}

class Currency {
  String currencyName;
  String forexBuying;
  String forexSelling;
  String banknotBuying;
  String banknotSelling;

  Currency._(this.currencyName, this.forexBuying, this.forexSelling,
      this.banknotBuying, this.banknotSelling);

  factory Currency.fromElement(XmlElement genreElement) {
    return Currency._(
        genreElement.getAttribute('CurrencyName'),
        genreElement.getAttribute('ForexBuying'),
        genreElement.getAttribute('ForexSelling'),
        genreElement.getAttribute('BanknotBuying'),
        genreElement.getAttribute('BanknotSelling'));
  }
}
```

rates.service.dart

```
import 'package:currency_rates/model/rates_model.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as Http;
import 'package:xml/xml.dart' as xml;

String url = "https://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml";

Future<TarihDate> getJsonFromUrl() async {
  var response = await Http.get(url);
  var raw = xml.XmlDocument.parse(response.body);
  var elements = raw.getElement("Tarih_Date");
  return TarihDate.fromElement(elements);
}
```

main.dart

```
body: FutureBuilder(
          future: getJsonFromUrl(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<TarihDate> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              print(snapshot.data.cList[0].currencyName);
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        snapshot.data.cList[index].forexBuying,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.cList.length);
            }
            return ErrorWidget(throw Exception("Error"));
          }),
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in `Currentcy.fromElement` you should be reading from child nodes, not attributes. For example, replace `genreElement.getAttribute('CurrencyName')` with `genreElement.getElement('CurrencyName').text`.

Note: There are also some misspellings of XML names in the same method (`BanknoteBuying` and `BanknoteSelling`).

Comment: Yeah , thank you I figured it out :). So whats difference between attributes and elements? Why didnt work getAttribute here? Thank you again !.

Comment: Please check the key terminology section on the Wikipedia article about [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Key_terminology).